# Solr can't update collection

Tags: java, solr

I'm trying to update Solr(4.10.1)'s collection using a json file

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/update?commit=true -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @myFile.json
```

When I run the above command I get this error:

> ERROR - 2014-10-07 12:54:29.813; org.apache.solr.common.SolrException; null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to invoke function processAdd in script: update-teaser.js: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot call method "length" of null (#13) in  at line number 13
>       at org.apache.solr.update.processor.StatelessScriptUpdateProcessorFactory$ScriptUpdateProcessor.invokeFunction(StatelessScriptUpdateProcessorFactory.java:433)
>       at org.apache.solr.update.processor.StatelessScriptUpdateProcessorFactory$ScriptUpdateProcessor.processAdd(StatelessScriptUpdateProcessorFactory.java:374)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader$SingleThreadedJsonLoader.handleAdds(JsonLoader.java:460)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader$SingleThreadedJsonLoader.processUpdate(JsonLoader.java:132)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader$SingleThreadedJsonLoader.load(JsonLoader.java:106)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader.load(JsonLoader.java:68)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:99)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:74)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
>       at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1967)
>       at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:777)
>       at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:418)
>       at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:207)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:953)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1014)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:861)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot call method "length" of null (#13) in  at line number 13
>       at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.invokeFunction(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.solr.update.processor.StatelessScriptUpdateProcessorFactory$ScriptUpdateProcessor.invokeFunction(StatelessScriptUpdateProcessorFactory.java:425)
>       ... 37 more
>   Caused by: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot call method "length" of null (#13)
>       at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.constructError(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.constructError(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.typeError(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.undefCallError(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThisHelper(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Interpreter.interpret(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.InterpretedFunction.call(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ContextFactory.doTopCall(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine$1.superDoTopCall(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine$1.doTopCall(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.InterpretedFunction.call(Unknown Source)
>       ... 40 more

Do you have any idea?

Comment: The problem looks to be at the time of the update script update-teaser.js. You could be missing a field in your json file. Have a look at line 13 of update-teaser.js in your conf directory to see what field it may be looking for. No luck then post your myfile.json and update-teaser.js

Comment: Thanks @everreadyeddy! It's exactly the problem...Now it works properly!